# Android app front-end with Django back-end auto login session

Tags: android, python, django

I used Android app front-end with Django back-end. But it hasn't auto login.

```
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login
def login_app(request):
    ...
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        ...
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        auth_login(request, user)
        ...
    return ...
```

When I call this func twice. It get a anonymous user instance.

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
```

How do I do so that can be True?
Set cookie? How?
Excuse for poor English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
```

It mains: the request user is login success. For example， people's cookie not out date。

when`auth_login`execute success，django will help you save user cookie and sesion。

example：
in templates:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please <a href={% url 'login_url' %}>log in</a>.</p>
{% endif %}
```

in views:

```
def my_view(request):
   if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('/login/')
```

in your login view:

```
def login_app(request):
    ...
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        #tell user he has login successful，or redict other page
    else:
        username = request.POST.get('username', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            auth_login(request, user)
        #tell user he login successfull
```

more info [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/)

your android app has reviced http response, it has cookie info, please save it and next request bring cookie.

django's doc is very ++ ,please read careful

Excuse for poor English.